# How can I generate a 3x2 image results grid using the MirrorAPI?

Tags: html, google-mirror-api

What is the correct HTML / JSON syntax to generate a timeline card of the format '6 imges on a grid' like the built-in image search generates? sample attached. I'd like it to be the lead card of a response bundle that my glassware is generating.

[image: image results on glass]

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard CSS with HTML to generate the pictures. One such example (using the playground to verify) follows and appears to work:

```
{
  "html": "<style>\n.box {\n  width: 210px;\n  height: 180px;\n  float: left;\n  border: thin solid white;\n}\n</style>\n\n    <div class=\"box\">\n      <img class=\"box\" src=\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-quy9Ox8dQJI/T3xUHhub6PI/AAAAAAAAHAQ/YvjqA3Pw1sM/glass_photos.jpg?sz=360\">\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"box\">\n      <img class=\"box\" src=\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-quy9Ox8dQJI/T3xUHhub6PI/AAAAAAAAHAQ/YvjqA3Pw1sM/glass_photos.jpg?sz=360\">\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"box\">\n      <img class=\"box\" src=\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-quy9Ox8dQJI/T3xUHhub6PI/AAAAAAAAHAQ/YvjqA3Pw1sM/glass_photos.jpg?sz=360\">\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"box\">\n      <img class=\"box\" src=\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-quy9Ox8dQJI/T3xUHhub6PI/AAAAAAAAHAQ/YvjqA3Pw1sM/glass_photos.jpg?sz=360\">\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"box\">\n      <img class=\"box\" src=\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-quy9Ox8dQJI/T3xUHhub6PI/AAAAAAAAHAQ/YvjqA3Pw1sM/glass_photos.jpg?sz=360\">\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"box\">\n      <img class=\"box\" src=\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-quy9Ox8dQJI/T3xUHhub6PI/AAAAAAAAHAQ/YvjqA3Pw1sM/glass_photos.jpg?sz=360\">\n    </div>\n\n",
  "notification": {
    "level": "DEFAULT"
  }
}
```

This uses floating divs with images in them to accomplish the effect. You could probably also use a table for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **Table** or **List** what ever u want. just use this class in **article** `class=\"mosaic mosaic6\"`

```
  {
      "html": "<article class=\"photo\">\n  <ul class=\"mosaic mosaic6\">\n    <li style=\"background-image: url(https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/links/washington.jpg)\"></li>\n    <li style=\"background-image: url(https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/links/lincoln.png)\"></li>\n    <li style=\"background-image: url(https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/links/obama.jpg)\"></li>\n  </ul>\n  <ul class=\"mosaic mosaic6\">\n    <li style=\"background-image: url(https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/links/washington.jpg)\"></li>\n    <li style=\"background-image: url(https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/links/lincoln.png)\"></li>\n    <li style=\"background-image: url(https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/links/obama.jpg)\"></li>\n  </ul>\n </article>\n",
      "notification": {
        "level": "DEFAULT"
      }
    }
```

[image]